# How to display Timer results on next `ViewController´

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer

I have 2 `ViewControllers`. 1 is for the game which has a timer. Second one is for the results. After pressing finish button on the game `ViewController` it goes to the result. How can I display the results of the timer on a label on the results `ViewController`?

This is my code for timer:

```
//these are initialized in games ViewController.h
IBOutlet UILabel *GameTimer;
int timeSec;
int timeMin;
NSTimer *timer;

//game ViewController.m under @implementation
INSString *timeNow;
NSTimer *timer1;
```

This is my methods of the timer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self performSelector:@selector(startTimer1) withObject: nil afterDelay:0.0];

}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void)startTimer1{

    //initializing 'timer1'
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(timerTick:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer1 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
//Event called every time the NSTimer ticks.
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer1
{
    timeSec++;
    if (timeSec == 60)
    {
        timeSec = 0;
        timeMin++;
    }
    //Format the string 00:00
    timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tiempo: %02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];
    //Display on your label
    //[timeLabel setStringValue:timeNow];
    GameTimer.text= timeNow;
}
//Call this to stop the timer event(could use as a 'Pause' or 'Reset')
- (void) StopTimer
{
    [timer invalidate];
    timeSec = 0;
    timeMin = 0;
    //Since we reset here, and timerTick won't update your label again, we need to refresh it again.
    //Format the string in 00:00
    timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];
    //Display on your label
    // [timeLabel setStringValue:timeNow];
    GameTimer.text= timeNow;
}
//executed after the finish button is pressed
- (IBAction)finishPressed:(id)sender{
}
```

EDIT:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    LetterResults6x6 *nextViewController = [[LetterResults6x6 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; //Let us assume that ViewController is the controller in which you wish to show the result.
    nextViewController.finalTime = timeNow; //here finalTime is a NSString property in ViewController Class
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
- (IBAction)finishPressed:(id)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"finished" sender: self];

}
```

EDIT 2 SOLUTION:
I figured it out. I did it in an easier way by adding few lines of code to the timer methods to record the results and then pass them in the other `ViewController`

```
- (void)timerTick:(NSTimer *)timer1
{
    timeSec++;
    if (timeSec == 60)
    {
        timeSec = 0;
        timeMin++;
    }
    //Format the string 00:00
    timeNow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tiempo: %02d:%02d", timeMin, timeSec];
    //Display on your label
    //[timeLabel setStringValue:timeNow];
    GameTimer.text= timeNow;
    //code i added
    NSUserDefaults *prefs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs1 setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",timeNow] forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
}
```

then add this to second ViewController .m

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *sc = [prefs1 stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

timerResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tiempo %@", sc];
```

Thanks for all the help guys :)

Comment: try to declare timer in a shared class (as AppDelegate but i recommend to create a new one) and get in every where you want in whole project

Comment: Tip: Just store the seconds.  Convert to minutes & seconds during presentation only (i.e. when formatting the string for the label or whatever).

Comment: you should not use user defaults to pass data between view controller, you are making yourself complicated !

Comment: well so far the only solution that works, dont know any other way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the string value to next controller while pushing to it,

If you are using `.xib`

```
ViewController *nextViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]; //Let us assume that ViewController is the controller in which you wish to show the result.
nextViewController.finalTime = timeNow; //here finalTime is a NSString property in ViewController Class
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
```

For `Storyboard`, use this code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {//Let us assume that ViewController is the controller in which you wish to show the result(i.e., Second controller).
        nextViewController.finalTime = timeNow; //here finalTime is a NSString property in ViewController Class
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

in first view controller `.m` file

```
//executed after the finish button is pressed
- (IBAction)finishPressed:(id)sender{
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender     
{ 
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[LetterResults6x6 class]]) { 

    nextViewController.finalTime = timeNow; //here finalTime is a NSString property in ViewController Class 
    } 
}
```

In `LetterResults6x6.h`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *finalTime;
```

In `LetterResults6x6.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.labelOutlet.text = self.finalTime;
}
```

Comment: Do i declare this in the first `ViewController` or the second one?

Comment: you should declare `finalTime` property in second controller

Comment: `nextViewController` is the results `ViewController`?

Comment: I tried the first code example and it seemed to work without giving any errors. I tried to display the timer results on a label using this line of code:        `timerResults.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tiempo: %@", finalTime];`. `timerResults` is the name of my `UILabel` that i want the timer results to be displayed on. When i run the app all i get is tiempo: (null). Do you know how to get them to be displayed on the label?

Comment: How are you transitioning from first to second view controller ?, i mean what did you write in `finishPressed` Method ?

Comment: im using this `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"finished" sender: self];`but it also works if i leave the method empty

Comment: so, copy paste the `prepareForSegue ` method from my answer in first view controller (the controller in which you implemented `finishPressed` method)

Comment: I edited my question to show where i added your code. let me know if i did something wrong?

Comment: just paste this in first view controller,

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[LetterResults6x6 class]]) {
        nextViewController.finalTime = timeNow; //here finalTime is a NSString property in ViewController Class
    }
}`

Comment: I get an error saying: `property finalTime not found on object of type LetterResults6x6`. where you had `nextViewController` i changed it to `LetterResults6x6` since its the name of my next `viewController`

Comment: Im still getting same error in` finalTime` and `self.labelOutlet.text`

Comment: what is the name of label in which you are displaying the result ?, (replace `self.labelOutlet. ` with that name)
Did you do declare `finalTime` property in  `LetterResults6x6.h` file ? ,(see the edit which i made in my answer, copy paste the code)

Comment: its `timerResults`, i did copy and paste ur code but it still seems to give that error. also it autocorrected to do it like this `self->timerResults.text = self.finalTime;` and now only this line keep giving the error `UIViewController.finalTime = timeNow;`

Comment: Did you do declare finalTime property in LetterResults6x6.h file ?

Comment: yes, `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* finalTime;`

Comment: `property finalTime not found on object of type LetterResults6x6`

Comment: if you define that property (i.e., `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *finalTime;`) In `LetterResults6x6.h` then it will not give the error !!

Comment: it still did but its ok now i found another way to do it, i edited my question with the solution, and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the value of your `timeSec` and `timeMin` while pushing `resultsViewController`.

**add this Properties in your ResultsViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic) int  timeSec;
@property (nonatomic) int  timeMin;
```

**Now in your GameViewController, add the following on this method:-**

```
//executed after the finish button is pressed
- (IBAction)finishPressed:(id)sender{
  ResultsViewController *resultViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ResultsViewController"];
   resultViewController.timeMin=timeMin;  //pass the value
   resultViewController.timeMin=timeSec;  //pass the value

  // now push to your ResultViewController

}
```

Comment: I used modal segue to transition between Views should i use different? Because now when i press finish button it crashes

Comment: I added this line of code to push the view but it still crashes `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"finished" sender: self];` should i do it differently?